# Scale label's font size or rotate label? (swift)

Tags: ios, swift

I'd like to fit some text in a label by either adjusting the font size or by rotating the label if the font becomes too small.  Using the following, I can shrink the font size down to a certain point (60% of the default in this example), but if that is not enough, any remaining characters that don't fit will be truncated.

```
label.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
label.minimumScaleFactor = 0.6
```

For example, `label.text = "This a long label"` gets truncated to `"This is a long l..."`. Each label can only have one line of text.

I then want to adjust other labels to the same new font size (or rotate them accordingly).

How can I tell what the new font size is?  Or what the actual scale factor is?  How can I tell if the text was truncated?

Comment: Rotate them accordingly? How will rotating text labels help? Wouldn't that look really strange?

Comment: Not at all, just rotated pi/2, they look normal. They are the x-axis labels of a graph.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you can solve this using the following line in your code which would "wrap" the text to fit the field, and not give the "..." and display the entire text:

```
label.numberOfLines = 0
```

Other than that, I'm not sure of a way to automatically change it, but perhaps you could use an "if" "then" statement to say something along the lines of:

```
"If" label.numberOfLines = <1, "then", label.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 42)
```

Put a lesser and lesser "ofSize" amount to until the text fully fits in the field.

Comment: I can only have one line of text.

Comment: Did you try the above method? You can change that variable to 1,2,3,4...etc. that will work for you.

Comment: I did not try it because I can only have one line of text.